# Optical communication module using LED and photodiode or sensors

Tags: led, wireless, digital-communications

I'm trying to build a wireless communication system using LED and photodiode sensors. The communication distance is at most a few meters away, and the communication speed can be around 10kbps or even less. 
I try to use pre-built modules for sender and receiver systems as a turn-key system, but I found none so far.

- Do you know where can I find some modules/kits or whatever that does the LED communication?
- If there is none, is there any schematics or documents/books so that I can use to build one?

Comment: Have you considered VLC (visible light communication)? Or maybe that's what you're talking about... Anyhow, you can find some example projects by Googling. Also, this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16626/what-solutions-if-any-are-there-for-visible-light-transmission-vlc

Comment: Am I the first one to think "IR remote control"?!? Arent there a couple *billion* of these devices in everyday use all over the planet? - I'm sure if you do any looking in that direction, you'll find plenty of television/vcr/stereo/whatever remote control LED & receiver pairs that should fit the parameters you've listed here.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB - Since standard remote control use a 38 kHz carrier and msec pulse timing, they are not suited for 10 kbs transmission. Which is what the OP requested.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Well, he did say "or less"...it's less! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The major challenge with communicating with light is interference from the SUN or 60Hz room lighting or 80,000Hz electronic-ballast fluorescent lights.

Sending a coded optical tone ----- 38KHz ----- is the simple and robust method.

You can recovery these tones using NE567 tone decoder, which provides a logic output upon arrival of a "strong tone". You will need to DC_block the input signal.

http://www.x-robotics.com/downloads/pdfs/NE567_SE567_2.pdf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFtR90.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The dual Rload, with Diode(s), allows high current operation at high photon fluxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can get two [USB Infrared Toy](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/USB_Infrared_Toy)s from Dangerous Prototypes. They use 38kHz demodulator at receiving side, which is pretty much a standard in infrared remotes. The device is open source and Python scriptable, so you will have a fun time hacking it for your application.